# Projecting EF Result sets onto complex object model is slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm running some queries in EF 6 (latest package found on NuGet) and have found that when I project (`IQueryable<T>.Select(...)`) the result set onto an object model which is fairly complex, the runtime of the projection (inflating the results into .NET objects - not SQL execution time) is very slow.

**Is this the expected behavior and is there any workaround?**

To reiterate, I have determined that executing the query on SQL server is acceptably fast.  I have also determined that network I/O is acceptably fast.  I have also observed that EF builds the SQL query from an IQueryable very quickly.  It seems that projecting the result set is by far the slowest part of the whole activity, consuming between 5 and 7 seconds for a result set of just a few rows.

I have further isolated the problem to several members of the model I'm projecting onto.  Three of these members are `IEnumerables<int>` and the 4th member is `IEnumerable<SomeObject>`.  `SomeObject` is very simple, containing just two public primitive members and nothing else.

Further testing reveals, that dropping any of those 4 members from my projection drops the runtime by a second or two each, which I interpret to be further confirmation that projecting onto an object composed of collections is the root cause of my slowdown.

Here's a concrete example of what I am trying to do.

```
public class MyBusinessObject {

    public int SomeMember {get;set;}
    public double SomeOtherMember {get;set;}
    //more primitive members here

    public IEnumerable<int> MyList {get;set;}
    //more collections here
}

//query is dynamically generated and will be considerably more complicated than this...
//...(more joins and inner selects), but it's bounded, and the runtime is acceptable to me
IQueryable<MyDbSetEntity> query = myContext.MyDbSet.Join(...).Where(...).OrderBy(...).Skip(...).Take(...).AsNoTracking();

IQueryable<MyBusinessObject> model = query.Select(myEntity => new MyBusinessObject {
    SomeMember = myEntity.SomeMember,
    SomeOtherMember = myEntity.SomeOtherMember,
    MyList = myEntity.MyList
});

//this is the line that takes forever - i have determined that walking the expression tree,...
//...generating the sql, running the sql, returing the data over the wire are all not implicated...
//...in the majority of the time spent with maybe a second spent on all of the aforementioned,...
//...and the remaining 5 or seconds spent building the list of objects.
List<MyBusinessObject> objects = model.ToList();
```

Comment: It will depend specifically on the objects and fields used in your exact scenario. Having a list of Int for instance isn't likely going to be a straight over mapping as I don't believe arrays map directly to DB columns. The things to check/try: Is it generating a single SQL statement when run, or multiple? Multiple would indicate lazy loading is still getting tripped. Next would be to try removing some of the various extra lists and seeing which result in the biggest hits. Looking over the resulting query can also identify data that might be too loosely joined.

Comment: @StevePy It's a single query for sure.  I went out of my way to be certain of that.  Each of the lists/collections seems to incur a second or two of extra time.

Comment: my first guess is that this is a problem with change tracking. Not materializing the objects but wiring up the relationships in the change tracker. Do you need to track the state of the results of this query? Even if you do, can you disable it for the query to see if there's an improvement in materializing the results?

Comment: @JulieLerman I have tried this already but forgot to indicate as much in the code sample.  I've updated the code sample to better reflect my scenario.  It did yield about 0.1 seconds of improvement.  Still, we have a good 5 - 8 seconds of mystery time while executing ToList.  One question I have is do I need to call AsNoTracking to each reference of myDbContext.MyDbSet<T> used to composed the IQueryable<T>?  We have several such references between Joins and inner selects, but I thought that the AsNoTracking call would apply to the singular underlying query found in the IQueryable<T>.  Thanks!